# geb: RequiredPageContentNotPresent after login request

Tags: geb

I have the following setup:

```
class LoginPage extends Page {
    def login() { //fill user/pass, click "login"}
}

class IndexPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        sideTabs { module SideTabs }
    }
}

class TabAPage extends Page {
    //...
}

class SideTabs extends Module {
    static content = {
        tabA(to: TabAPage) { $(".sidetab-label", text: "tab A") }
    }
}

class TabALoginSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setup() {
        to LoginPage
    }

    def "test foo"() { /* ... */ }

    def "test bar"() {

        when: 
        login()
//        report "after login"
        at IndexPage
        sideTabs.tabA.click()
        //...

        then: 
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I execute "test bar", I get:

```
geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'IndexPage -> sideTabs: SideTabs -> tabA: geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present
```

When I execute "test bar" and uncomment the report line, test passes.

So I'm guessing the problem lies in "at IndexPage" returning before the page has finished loading. I don't think login() should wait on any content, because if the login fails, then there's no content loading issue, and if login succeeds - the page transitions to Index. I've attempted adding `wait:true` to tabA's content definition, to no avail.

Funnily, on the screenshots geb produces in the wake of "test bar"'s failure, I can actually spot the tabA element...

Help appreciated.

### Update:

adding

```
void onLoad(Page previousPage) {
    waitFor { sideTabs.tabA }
}
```

to IndexPage seems to iron-out the problem so-far. I'm unclear why adding `wait:true` to the content definition did not yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a required:false should work but placed here:

```
class SideTabs extends Module {
    static content = {
        tabA(required:false, to: TabAPage) { $(".sidetab-label", text: "tab A") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for all of the content to load before interacting with the page then use `required: false` when defining your content.

e.g.

```
class IndexPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        sideTabs(required: false) { module SideTabs }
    }
}
```

The intended use of the required statement is for hidden content that can be made visible after page interaction. But it should help in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks @CommodoreBeard, but afraid that doesn't stop the a/m exception from triggering.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to add the `at` in the *IndexPage* class, check documentation [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-checking).

Your class should look like:

```
class IndexPage extends Page {

static at = {...}

static content = {
    sideTabs { module SideTabs }
    }
}
```

I think that using the `report` slows down the test, causing the page to render correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Royg. IndexPage actually has an ```at{}``` checker. The above is just an exerpt with the pieces I thought relevant to the problem I encountered.

Comment: Does your `at{}` check for the module?  did you try to wrap the `click()` with `waitFor`?